# How do I temporarily change the axis of rotation of an object in blender?

Tags: animation, axis

I'm trying to rotate an array of objects (disconnected from each other) that rotate about some other axis initially

Comment: By array you mean array modifier? Is the complete array is to be rotated or each individual object?

Comment: You can add an Empty and Parent them all to it, then you can rotate the Empty.